# C Programmıng Error invalid operands to binary int and long long unsigned integer

Tags: c, codeblocks

```
void add_book(FILE *bookfile){ book_t add ={0, "", "", "", 0, ""};

if ((bookfile = fopen("kitaplar.txt", "rb+")) == NULL)
{
    printf("dosya olusmadi ");
    return 1;
}
else
{
    printf("Book ID: ");
    scanf("%d",&add.book_id);
    while(add.book_id != 0)
    {
        printf("Book name: ");
        scanf("%s",
              add.book_name);
        printf("Writer: ");
        scanf("%s",
              add.writer);
        printf("Publisher: ");
        scanf("%s",
              add.publisher);
        printf("How many times borrowed: ");
        scanf("%d",
              &add.number_of_borrowing);
        printf("Status: ");
        scanf("%s",
              add.status);
        fseek(
              bookfile,**(add.book_id - 1) * sizeof(book_t)**,
              SEEK_SET
              );
        fwrite(&add, sizeof(book_t), 1, bookfile);
        printf("Book ID: ");
        scanf("%d",&add.book_id);

    }
    fclose(bookfile);

}

return main();
```

}

```
typedef struct book{
int book_id[4];
char book_name[32];
char writer[32];
char publisher[32];
int number_of_borrowing;
char status[12];
}book_t;
```

> error : invalid operands to binary * (have 'int *' and 'long long unsigned int')

The problem is in this part it says

```
(add.book_id - 1) * sizeof(book_t)
```

I have been looking site and internet for solution. Someones got similar error but cant get it how to fix this one.

Comment: `scanf("%s", add.status)` expects a pointer to a `char` array but the struct has `int status[12];`. That isn't what the question title says though. Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste the **text** of the code.

Comment: `fseek()` takes a `long` argument but you have provided one of `size_t` which might be equavalent to `unsigned long long`. On MS Visual C `long` is only 32 bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, they have not. `add.book_id` is an array, which is converted to a pointer, so `(add.book_id - 1) * sizeof(book_t)` is an invalid expression (attempting to multiply a pointer), not a `size_t` or `long` argument.

Comment: @EricPostpischil two errors then. OP seems to be under the impression that `add.book_id` is `int` with that and `scanf("%d", &add.book_id);`

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you i fixed {int status[12];} to {char status[12];}

Answer (score 1):

The member `book_id` is defined as an array, `int book_id[4]`. Why is it an array instead of just an `int`?

In the expression `(add.book_id - 1) * sizeof(book_t)`, the array `add.book_id` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Then `- 1` subtracts one, attempting to make it point to where an element before the first element would be. The type of the result is `int *`, a pointer to an integer.

Then `* sizeof(book_t)` attempts to multiply this pointer. You cannot multiply a pointer. This is what the compiler error message is telling you.

If you want to use the first element of `book_id` as a one-based index into the file, you can change the expression to `(add.book_id[0]-1) * sizeof add`. Or, if you do not need an array, you can change the definition of the member to `int book_id;`.

Comment: Array was professors order. Now i do understand why do i get errors. Your solution works perfectly fine it is gonna help me to fix other errors thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`(add.book_id - 1)` is a pointer. There is no pointer multiplication operation defined in the C standard - thus the error.